# Symfony 3: Integrate Wordpress for FRONTEND NICE DISPLAY PURPOSE

Tags: wordpress, symfony, web-frontend, symfony-3.2

I am looking for solutions to integrate WordPress to Symfony 3.

My Symfony 3 project is running well with its own custom functionalities **but the landing page looks lame compare to a WordPress landing page**.

Now I want to **update the visual of the landing page**. Knowing that is something easy to do with a WordPress template, I am looking for this solution. (I might delegate the building of the WordPress site but need to be sure I can connect it with my existing Symfony 3 project.)

I found plenty of input on the subject, most of them are olds like: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506096/integrating-wordpress-with-symfony) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804182/wordpress-symfony-co-habitation).

There is also the [EkinoWordpressBundle](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle) and [symfony-wordpress-edition](https://github.com/outlandishideas/symfony-wordpress-edition). But those seem to integrate Symfony within WordPress, and as I only require WordPress for display purposes I'd rather have it the other way around.

Any suggested direction to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Place your wordpress installation into the /web folder e.g /blog
2. edit your symfony .htaccess file, then comment out this line.

   DirectoryIndex app.php

Run your Wordpress as normal i.e wwww.domain.com/blog